# How much energy (watts) is lost due to heat from a 400 Watt Metal Halide bulb?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, electricity

How much energy (watts) is lost due to heat from a 400 Watt Metal Halide (MH) bulb?

I'd like to get maybe like a percentage or rough estimate and a way to derive that answer ideally.

I'm trying to see how much strain MH bulbs place on the cooling load of say an office.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but probably [useful information out MH tube economics](http://www.hoveyelectric.com/hovey-electric-power-blog/bid/81362/Maintenance-Cost-Comparison-400-Watt-Metal-Halide-vs-Fluorescent-T5)

Answer (score 5):

For the purposes of what they do to a cooling load in a closed environment, all $400 \operatorname{W}$ is added heat. That's because part of thermodynamics is that no real process is completely reversible (in the sense that it generates no new entropy), and every increase in entropy entails some energy being "thermalized" (changed into waste heat). So, what happens with the light is it will bounce around the office a few times, depending on how reflective the surfaces are, and eventually be absorbed by one of them and turned into heat.

The net amount of energy that manages to escape out of windows is probably negligible, especially if the windows are letting sunlight in, but you can measure how much light is escaping the windows at night, how much light is coming in, and estimate the net energy flow by assuming something about the shape of the spectrum. I say "estimate" because it's probably not worth your while to actually measure the spectrum.